# Neo4J most and least shots of the teams in the season

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a graph database and i am trying to find out which team has the most and the least shots in the season. i got until this point[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nruvh.png)
Could you give me some hints how to find out the number of shots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with design . Ideally, You have to give common label(like "Team") for all the teams . And relation with event anyway can help in finding which is away team and which is home team  and number of shots can be a property in the relation.

i would like to know if there are multiple nodes for same team in your graph to help you in this case.

Comment: I will try now to redesign everything and create it as you said

Comment: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///D:/neo4j_as.csv'  AS row
CREATE(m:Event{date:row.Date, home_team:row.HomeTeam, away_team:row.AwayTeam, fulltime_result:row.FTR, halftime_result:row.HTR})
CREATE(at:AwayTeam{name:row.AwayTeam, fulltime_goals:toInteger(row.FTAG), halftime_goals:toInteger(row.HTAG),
away_shots:toInteger(row.AS)})
CREATE(ht:HomeTeam{name:row.HomeTeam, fulltime_goals:toInteger(row.FTHG),
halftime_goals:toInteger(row.HTHG),
home_shots:toInteger(row.HS)})
MERGE (r:Ref{name:row.Referee})
MERGE (r)-[:REFFED]->(m)
CREATE(at)-[:PLAYED_AWAY]->(m)<-[:PLAYED_HOME]-(ht)

Comment: This is my initial design

Comment: @AdamBruzac , use the following query 
`LOAD data as row CREATE(m:Event{date:row.Date, home_team:row.HomeTeam, away_team:row.AwayTeam, fulltime_result:row.FTR, halftime_result:row.HTR}) 
MERGE (at:Team{name:row.AwayTeam}) 
MERGE (ht:Team{name:row.HomeTeam})
CREATE (at)-[:PLAYED_AWAY{fulltime_goals:toInteger(row.FTAG), halftime_goals:toInteger(row.HTAG), away_shots:toInteger(row.AS)}]->(m)
CREATE (ht)-[:PLAYED_HOME{ fulltime_goals:toInteger(row.FTHG), halftime_goals:toInteger(row.HTHG), home_shots:toInteger(row.HS)}]->(m)
MERGE (r:Ref{name:row.Referee}) MERGE (r)-[:REFFED]->(m)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use ORDER BY keyword to sort by shots, e.g.

```
RETURN a.away_shorts, m.away_team, m.home_team, b.home_shots 
ORDER BY a.away_shots 
//sort by order ascending, use ORDER BY a.away_shots DESC to reverse
```

If you wanted to only return the first team with, for example the least away shots, you might do something like this:

```
MATCH (a.AwayTeam)-[:PLAYED_AWAY]->(m:Event)<-[:PLAYED_HOME]-(b:HomeTeam)
RETURN a.away_shots, m.away_team, m.home_team, b.home_shots
ORDER BY a.away_shots LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The thing is the away shots are not the total shots of the teams. There are more matches and i don`t know how to sum all the shots from all the teams

Comment: What exactly are you looking to query? I'm not quite sure

Comment: I am importing the data from an csv file. I have some columns, away team, home team, away shots and home shots, match date and i have all the matches from last season of PL. The question is to find out which teamhad the most shots and least shots in the whole season. The shots in the pic is for each game

Comment: as in home shots + away shots per team?

Comment: Yes. I`m sorry i didn`t know how to explain

Comment: So, i did some thinking and i created an index on the names from the away team and the names from the home team and i returned the name and the sum of the away_shots and if i run this code 

MATCH (a:AwayTeam)
WHERE EXISTS(a.name)
RETURN a.name, SUM(a.away_shots)

as a result i get all the away teams with the total of shots per team, but i am confused again because i don`t know how i can add it with the home shots